# Learning expression trees in LINQ

Tags: linq, expression-trees

What articles/tutorials can you recommend for LINQ Expression Trees?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/charlie/expression-tree-basics)
​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Answer (score 2):

If you grok this [Building an `IQueryable` provider](https://web.archive.org/web/20160228161503/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/mattwar/archive/2008/11/18/linq-links.aspx), then you grok `System.Linq.Expressions`. But you can also start with the simple [Expression Tree Basics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/charlie/expression-tree-basics).

Answer (score 2):

From MSDN, [Expression Trees (C# and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx)

Comment: Also, if you don't have this app it might help you with your LINQ: http://www.linqpad.net/