# lambda expression meaning/modificating

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

I'm having problem with a lambda expression which is used for custom filtering of data from `DataGridView`.

This is the expression:

```
private static Expression<Func<T, bool>> ExpressionLongEquals<T>(string Key, long Value)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    // create expression for param => param.TEntityNameId == PrimaryKey
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
        Expression.Equal(
            Expression.Property(param, Key),
            Expression.Constant(Value)),
        param);
    return lambda;
}
```

The problem is that I have a case when the `Value` argument is of type `long?` which as it seems is acceptable but after completing this code I get an error that `Method equal is not defined for Nullable1.System.Int64 and System.Int64`. I have difficulties with understanding this method, not very sure that it's understandable for the others outside the context but however I'm gonna post my questions - first, what exactly is this, by which I mean - what I need to learn/read in order to be able with such kind of code like the one I posted and second. I'm pretty sure this method works with `long` values and make problems only when `long?` is passed as argument so is there any way to modify it to solve this problem?

The need of `long?`values is recent and this is what cause the problem generally I do this:

```
else if (property.PropertyType == typeof(long?))
{
    long value = Convert.ToInt64(rule.Data);
    selector = ExpressionLongEquals<T>(rule.Field, value);
}
```

but still I get the error about `equal not defined for Nullable1.System.Int64 and System.Int64`.

Comment: How can `Value` be `long?` when the function signature demands that it's simply `long`?

Comment: @Jon: The property is `long?`.

Comment: See the edited code. As I said I don't fully understand so I'm not sure which parts are important for solving the problem. Maybe it will be enough for now to guide me to e specific issues that I have to learn/read in order to cope better with this.

Comment: 2 months experience in .NET and working on hand-cranked `Expression` stuff, impressive :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USE this...If I am correct you have to convert your value to a type of long?

```
private static Expression<Func<T, bool>> ExpressionLongEquals<T>(string Key, long Value)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    // create expression for param => param.TEntityNameId == PrimaryKey
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
        Expression.Equal(
            Expression.Property(param, Key),
            Expression.Constant(Value, typeof(long?)),
        param);
    return lambda;
}
```

Comment: Thanks `Gopesh Sharma` this works just as I wanted. Could you tell me something more specific to look up in order to get used to working with such kind of code?

Comment: @Leron See whenever you are dealing with some nullable values you have to convert it to nullable type, mainly when you are assigning or comparing(ex: equals)

Comment: Yeah, this is what solves the current problem, what I meant is what I need to read/learn in order to be more prepared to wrok with `Expression`, `Func`, `Equal` and all this stuff. I know this is strongly coupled with lambda but still, could you tell me more specific parts of `lambda` that refers to exactly those type of situations so I can learn bit by bit only the things that I need and use? Thanks.

Comment: @Leron see eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035418/learning-expression-trees-in-linq http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217539/net-expression-trees-tutorial